# Consumers to be able to send a message only to the Producer in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, console-application

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I'm trying to create a 1 `producer/server` with 2 (or many) `consumers/clients`. When the producer sends a message, all the consumers will receive the message. then any consumer can also send a message and only the producer will receive the message. Also, the producer knows which consumer sent the message.

Currently when I send a message from the consumer, all of them receives the message and that is not what I'm trying to do, is the above scenario possible in RabbitMQ and can someone give an example? Thanks!

producer

```
   Console.WriteLine("Producer");
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare("test-exchange", ExchangeType.Fanout);
            var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
            channel.QueueBind(queueName, "test-exchange", "");

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

            while (true)
            {
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
                if (message == "exit") break;

                var body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                channel.BasicPublish("test-exchange", "", null, body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
            }
```

consumer 1

```
   Console.WriteLine("Consumer 1");
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare("test-exchange", ExchangeType.Fanout);
            var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
            channel.QueueBind(queueName, "test-exchange", "");

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

            while (true)
            {
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
                if (message == "exit") break;

                var body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                channel.BasicPublish("test-exchange", "", null, body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
            }
```

Consumer 2 with same code as Consumer 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using a "fanout" exchange. Use a "direct" or "topic" exchange, and then publish using an appropriate "routing key", depending on which consumer queue(s) you want to receive the message.